# Azure App Service for Linux disk out of space after several deployment from Docker container

Tags: linux, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

We are having the issue when disk out of space after several Docker image deployment. So it seems all images saved on the Hard Disk :( And it seems this issue already exists for 3+ years.
We are going to use only `latest` image instead of versioned image. Will it help us? Or there are other ways to mitigate this issue? 
Is there any mechanism that we can use to clean images?

Moreover, We found that disk space is 70% in use in the New App Service for Linux, without any deployment! ([Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypSfM.png)). How this can happen, We are paying for 100% free disk.

Thanks a lot, in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you can post your question over on [sf] where system and network administrators help people.